# JSoup login times out

Tags: jsoup

I'm aware this sort of question has been asked in the past (a lot), so I'm sorry about yet another question on this topic, but nothing I've seen has helped so far. I'm trying to log into [my school gradebook](https://student.cps.k12.il.us/) using JSoup (unfortunately there is no API for the gradebook). Here's my code:

First, a GET request to the login page:

```
    Connection.Response loginGet = Jsoup.connect("https://student.cps.k12.il.us/pc/StudentLogin.aspx")
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute();
```

Next, a POST request to the login page (with login inputs, including hidden ones, and cookies from the GET request):

```
    Connection.Response login = Jsoup.connect("https://student.cps.k12.il.us/pc/StudentLogin.aspx")
        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
        .cookies(loginGet.cookies())
        .data("AuthType", "Student")
        .data("FormType", "Login")
        .data("DistrictID", "3000005")
        .data("Username", "username")
        .data("Password", "password")
        .data("cmdLogOn", "Sign+In")
        .execute();
```

Finally, a GET request to the grades page:

```
    Document grades = Jsoup.connect("https://student.cps.k12.il.us/pc/ParentStudentGrades.aspx")
        .cookies(login.cookies())
        .get();
```

The last request gives me the login page and an error about how it's logged me out because of a timeout, which I think might mean that it's logging in fine, but the cookie expires immediately. Also, when I login through Chrome, there are several cookies, but with JSoup there is only one (but that one is the session ID, so I *think* that's fine). Any ideas on what could be going wrong/how to fix it/more info needed?

Answer (score 0):

Things to consider:

- `.data("cmdLogOn", "Sign+In")` Did you try space instead of `+`?
- Try adding referer to the request where you POST user data: `.referer("https://student.cps.k12.il.us/pc/StudentLogin.aspx")`
- When you login using a browser you can also see using debugger what headers are sent. Maybe web server is expecting one of these headers. Example `.header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")`

Comment: Thanks, but none of those worked. The weird thing is, it works fine with Postman, just not with JSoup. Also, `cmdLogOn` is actually an optional thing (browser and Postman work without it), so it's not an issue with that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure it out, so I moved to [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and [PersistentCookieJar](https://github.com/franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar/), and just use JSoup for parsing only.